# iOS error msg: Break or Case Statement not in loop or switch

Tags: ios, loops, case, break

New to programming. Created a quiz application w/ different categories using a random number generator and case statements for the questions for each category. I have 2 issues.
 One is a line in the .m file. Each category starts with  -(IBAction)xyz:(id)sender;  On one line I keep getting the error message "expected expression". I also noticed w/ this line that the circle on the side indicating button link does not appear. I tried re-linking button, but i get the same error message.

(Not sure if first issue causing second issue)The second issue is in this same category in .m file I keep getting these error messages: Break or case statement not in loop or switch.I have copy&pasted code to make sure indentations and spelling correct from categories that do not have this error statement, but  I still get these error messages in this part of the code. I do not know how to fix it. Please help. I included lines with the said errors. Thx
`

}

```
-(IBAction)OphthalmicInstruments:(id)sender{

    Cat1.hidden = YES;
    Cat2.hidden = YES;

    BasicOptics.hidden = YES;
    EyeAnatomy.hidden = YES;
    OphthalmicInstruments.hidden = YES;
    Lenses.hidden = YES;
    Transposition.hidden = YES;
    Standards.hidden = YES;
    Frames.hidden = YES;
    Random.hidden = YES;
    Question.hidden = NO;

    Answer1.hidden = NO;
    Answer2.hidden = NO;
    Answer3.hidden = NO;
    Answer4.hidden = NO;

    Right1.hidden = YES;
    Right2.hidden = YES;
    Right3.hidden = YES;
    Right4.hidden = YES;

    Wrong1.hidden = YES;
    Wrong2.hidden = YES;
    Wrong3.hidden = YES;
    Wrong4.hidden = YES;

    SelectCategory.hidden = YES;

int OphthalmicInstrumentsQuestion = rand() % 33;
switch (OphthalmicInstrumentsQuestion) {
    case 0:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The PD ruler is used to measure:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intepupillary distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
        break;
    case 1:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A distometer measures:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interpupillary distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
        break;
    case 2:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A tonometer measures:"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interpupillary distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
        break;
    case 3: 
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A lens clock measures:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Interpupillary distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex distance"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intraocular pressure"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basecurve"];
        break;
    case 4:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A pupillometer uses a light to get a reflection from the :"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cornea"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Retina"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Iris"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sclera"];
        break;
    case 5:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In this system a hypothetical box surrounds each lens, and it is used for standard measurements of lenses and frames:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MRP"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boxing"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dato"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monel"];
        break;
    case 6:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A,B,C,DBL,ED,PC, & DBL are all part of what standard measuring system?"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MRP"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Datum"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boxing"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Monel"];
        break;
    case 7:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing Measurement system for lenses and frames the A represents:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance Between Lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum Blank Size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        break;
    case 8:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing Measurement system for lenses and frames the DBL represents:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance Between Lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum Blank Size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        break;
    case 9:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing Measurement system for lenses and frames the ED represents:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance Between Lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum Blank Size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        break;
    case 10:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing Measurement system for lenses and frames the B represents:"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance Between Lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum Blank Size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        break;
    case 11:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The geometric center line in the Boxing Measurement system is:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance Between Lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A Measurement"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"B Measurement"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"C Measurement"];
        break;
    case 12:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing System for lenses and frames the C represents:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance of lens through geometric center"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum blank size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal measurement"];
        break;
    case 13:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing System for lenses and frames the DBC represents:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance between lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance between centers"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal measurement"];
        break;
    case 14:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing System for lenses and frames the DBC can also represent:"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance between lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum blank size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame PD"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal measurement from outer to inner lens edge"];
        break;
    case 15:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In the Boxing System for lenses and frames if there is no prism the MRP is the same as:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance between lenses"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minimum blank size"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Geometric center"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Optical center"];
        break;
    case 16:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"On a finished lens, this vertical measurement is from the top of the segment to the lowest part of the lens edge?"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Height"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Inset"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decentration"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Compensation"];
        break;
    case 17:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This measurement is the difference between the Distance PD and the Near Pd?"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Height"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Inset"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decentration"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Compensation"];
        break;
    case 18:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The horizontal distance between the MRP (Major Reference Point) and the GC(Geometric Center)?"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Height"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Inset"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decentration"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Compensation"];
        break;
    case 19:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The correction for the difference between where the eyeglasses are actually worn and the distance the patient is refracted?"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Height"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment Inset"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decentration"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Compensation"];
        break;
    case 20:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the distance from the cornea to the back surface of the eyeglass lens:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Base Curve"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NPD"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertex Compensation"];
        break;
    case 21:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"According to the textbook, what is the proper bifocal placement?"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at pupil center"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at lower eyelid"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at lowest part of the pupil"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top above pupil center"];
        break;
    case 22:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"According to the textbook, what is the proper trifocal placement?"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at pupil center"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at lower eyelid"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top at lowest part of the pupil"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Segment top above pupil center"];
        break;
    case 23:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What must be done first to properly measure bifocal height?"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Determine vertex distance"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take patients PD"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clean the frame"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Adjust the frame"];
        break;
    case 24:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This part of the lensometer holds the lens against the lens stop:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Clamp"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Table"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Power Drum"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Axis Drum"];
        break;
    case 25:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This part of the lensometer provides a flat horizontal surface for the eyeglasses to rest:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Clamp"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Table"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Power Drum"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Axis Drum"];
        break;
    case 26:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This part of the lensometer consists of a wheel that turns and is calibrated in diopters:"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Clamp"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Table"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Power Drum"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Axis Drum"];
        break;
    case 27:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This part of the lensometer consists of a wheel that turns and is calibrated in degrees:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Clamp"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Table"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Power Drum"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Axis Drum"];
        break;
    case 28:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This tool is used to measure lens thickness:"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Calipers"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End Piece Angling Plier"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distometer"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Geneva Lens Clock"];
        break;
    case 29:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This tool can be used to adjust pantoscopic tilt:"];
        Right2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Calipers"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End Piece Angling Plier"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Axis Turning Plier"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Geneva Lens Clock"];
        break;
    case 30:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This tool can be used to adjust temple spread:"];
        Right3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Calipers"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End Piece Angling Plier"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Padded Holding Plier"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lens Axis Turning Plier"];
        break;
    case 31:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This tool can be used to cut the end of screws:"];
        Right4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Round Plier"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End Piece Angling Plier"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Padded Holding Plier"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chappel plier"];
        break;
    case 32:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a chart of horizontal and vertical intersecting lines used to analyze changes in the macula."];
        Right1.hidden = NO;
        Wrong2.hidden = NO;
        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Amslers Grid"];
        Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duochrome Test"];
        Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cover/Uncover Test"];
        Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Schirmers Test"];
        break;





    default:
        break;



}
```

Just posted the full case with the error. The line with the error message "expected expression" is `-(IBAction)OphthalmicInstruments:(id)sender{`

Comment: Can you post the code where the expression expected error occurs also please add the full code switch case(above code is only a part).

Comment: BTW - It is a very common convention in Objective-C to name classes with a leading uppercase letter. Method names and variables names should being with a lowercase letter. It makes your code easier to read by everyone.

Comment: 2nd note - Get rid of all of your calls to `stringWithFormat:`. Simply do: `Question.text = @"Some Text";`. Only use `stringWithFormat` when you actually have a format string.

Comment: The first line of the code posted here is the line where "expected error" occurs.

Comment: Is that the full method? Did you close the curly braces? Or you didn't paste it?

The "expected expression" error indicates that something has gone wrong (probably missing braces) BEFORE the first line.

Comment: I do have curly braces at the end I just did not paste it here correctly

Comment: @MonicaCanty: You are missing semicolons or } braces on any of the methods above the `OphthalmicInstruments` method

Comment: Often when you see that "expected expression" error (esp at the first line of a method declaration), the problem rests not with the code in question, but rather the code above it, where you might be missing a closing parenthesis or closing brace.

Comment: ok I will check all of this out. Thx.

Comment: @Rob: Your answer helped me the most. I was missing a curly brace in the code above it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just syntax error, check for semicolons & curly braces.

Comment: I was missing a curly brace in the code above that line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(){

case 1: {

}

case 2: {

}

}
```

try putting your cases in  {..} , that worked for me last time.

Comment: You only need curly braces for a given `case` statement if the first line of the block declares a variable.